# Ember App Kit: Importing Dependencies which would otherwise reside in App namespace

Tags: ember.js, ember-app-kit

Until now I developed my `Ember.js` projects following the structure & codes of [`@trek github` project](https://github.com/trek/ember-todos-with-build-tools-tests-and-other-modern-conveniences) which uses the `grunt-neuter` dependency to glue everything together.

I created many `util` classes that my application needs, all within the `App.` namespace and everything was working as expected :)

Now, I want to start with Stefan Penners `ember-app-kit` and I run into problems implementing my own `util` classes all the way down... For example I'm not able to fetch a `util` class twice:

```
import AuthenticationManager from 'myapp/utils/authentication/manager';
import Ajax from 'myapp/utils/ajax';

var App = Ember.Application.extend({
  modulePrefix: 'myapp'
});

Ember.Application.initializer({
  name: 'setup_1',

  initialize: function (container, application) {
    Ajax.setup(someSecurityRelatedValues);
    AuthenticationManager.setup({
      someProperty: ''
    });
  }
});

export default App;
```

---

```
import Ajax from 'myapp/utils/ajax';

var AuthenticationManager = Ember.Object.create({

  setup: function (someProperty) {
    // do something very important
    Ajax.get('ajax/path/to/server', {data: someData}).then(function (data) { // <-- Ajax is always "undefined"!
      // more important stuff to do ;)
    }));
  }
});

export default AuthenticationManager;
```

Somehow it's possible to get the `Ajax` dependency within the `Ember.Application.initializer` context, but within the `AuthenticationManager` context the `Ajax` dependency is always `undefined` and no further error/message is given...

What am I doing wrong here?